# AutoSizer and Chakra not working together

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

I'm trying to create a table that accepts inputs from `AutoSizer` while also having a scrollbar (by using `Box` from the `chakra-ui` framework).

In the below code, it will display a blank page. However, if I comment out the use of `AutoSizer`, it'll display as expected. Also, if I comment out `Box`, it'll display as expected. It's only when `Autosizer` and `Box` are used together, it doesn't work. What could be occurring here?

```
    <AutoSizer>
      {({ height, width }) => (
        <Box overflowX="auto" overflowY="auto">
        <Table>
          <Thead>
            {columns.map((col, i) => (
              <Th>{`Th ${i + 1}`}</Th>
            ))}
          </Thead>
          <Tbody>
            <Tr>
              {columns.map((col, i) => (
                <Td>{`Td ${i + 1}`}</Td>
              ))}
            </Tr>
          </Tbody>
        </Table>
        </Box>
      )}
    </AutoSizer>
```

Here's the code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/responsive-table-forked-figk7?file=/src/ResponsiveTable.tsx